# Macro to delete last row in table

Tags: excel, excel-2013, delete-row, vba

I have a table in Excel filled with data.

Is there any way to create a macro that deletes the last row in the table and automatically updates the new table range to NOT include that row?

Comment: @pnuts : That did the trick! Thank you

Comment: do you need to actually delete it or just empty it? VBA can be avoided if you don't need to delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this suited:

> select a cell within it and run `Selection.End(xlDown).Delete Shift:=xlUp`